# "SameSite Cookies" how to fix on html website?

Tags: html, adsense

I was looking into the reason why my website won't show any google ads and I found this little error that I don't know how to fix. I've searched it on multiple websites, please help.[image]

Comment: Also : My website is an http website, it is not "secure"

Comment: [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied and offer poor usability. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.